# python hypchat user message

Tags: python, hipchat

I'm using the [HypChat](https://github.com/RidersDiscountCom/HypChat) library but having some issues doing something simple, like sending myself a message.

I'm looking through [HipChat V2 API](https://hipchat.com/account/api) and I can create API tokens to do things like "Send Message" or "View Group".

My issue is that I can't figure out how to combine these actions - if I use my "Send Message" token, I can't create a `user` object, getting a `403: This action requires view_group`. But if I use the "View Group" token to successfully create the user, I can't send messages, getting a `403: This action requires send_message`.

Is there some other way to piece this together that I'm overlooking? I've yet to see a clear, unified example anywhere (other hipchat libraries, hipchat's official documentation, or HypChat) walking a user through creating the correct token and sending a message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a HipChat V2 API token, you can select more than one scope for it.

To do this, press the CTRL key (or Command if on MacOS) while selecting the additional scopes.

[image: hipchat token creation screenshot]

Comment: Boy do I feel dumb... works like a charm. Thanks! In my (slight) defense - it doesn't say anywhere on there that you can select multiple... but I should've tried, shame on me.

Comment: Nothing to feel bad about, that UX is hard to discover.